# multidimensional PHP array of arrays to HTML table question

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've seen similar questions, but my issue is that My array is more complex than the ones i've seen and I'm not skilled enough as yet to extrapolate.
I have an array as a constant, and I need to echo it into a table.

Here is what I came up with.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach (TAX_RATES as $val => $key) {
    foreach($key as $kk =>$vv){
        foreach($vv as $aa => $bb){
            echo '<tr><td>'."$bb</br>".'</td>';
        }
        echo '<td>'."$kk</br>".'</td>';
    }
echo '<td>'."$val</br>".'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Here is my array:

```
define('TAX_RATES',  
    array(
        'Single' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10,15,28,33,35,39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0,8275,37650,91150,190150,413350,415050),
            'MinTax' => array(0,927.50,5183.75,18558.75,46278.75,119934.75,120529.75)
        ),
        'Married_Jointly' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0,18550,75300,151900,231450,413350,466950),
            'MinTax' => array(0,1855,10367.5,29517.5,51791.5,111818.5,130578.5)
        ),
        'Married_Separately' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0,9275,37650,75950,115728,206675,233475),
            'MinTax' => array(0,927.5,5183.75,14758.75,25895.75,55909.25,65289.25)
        ),
        'Head_Household' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0,13250,50400,130150,210800,413350,441000),
            'MinTax' => array(0,1325,6897.5,26835,49417,116258.5,125936)
        )
    )
    );
```

The minTax value is just needed to calculate the actual tax.
The desired outcome is

```
Single
Income Range          Tax
0                      0
8275                "927.50 + .1*income" (i can figure this part out)
37650               "5183.75 + .15*income"
etc                 etc
```

Comment: You are creating a table row for each single value inside the inner loop … _“The desired outcome is”_ - what, just two columns? You are creating _way_ too many TD in your code for that, don’t you think?

Comment: yeah, I'm out of my depth. Was shown only very basic examples and left to figure out the mass of the sun, so to speak. I was shown how to loop through a way more simple array, and not shown anything about making tables.

Comment: You want to output the ranges and tax rates next to each other here, so you can not just loop over each of those individually, one after the other. I’d recommend using a `for` loop in that place, so that you can access the appropriate elements from both of those sub-arrays via index at the same time.

Comment: Guess this should be close, https://3v4l.org/025UC ?

Comment: tis lovely. I had tried something similar earlier but I now see that I didn't understand how it worked properly. Still not quite there. what is the [i] doing, specifically after ['Ranges']? Is that like an index number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure out from the below byu changing tr td

```
foreach($data as $k => $v)
{
  echo "<tr><td>$k</td></tr>";
    foreach($v as $key => $value)
    {
      echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td></tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++) {
        echo "<td>".$value[$i]."</td>"; 
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

[image]